# I just purchased a batch of TL081CP opamps and would like to know what the codes on the bottom mean

Tags: operational-amplifier

There is a random marking on each one. none the same. What does this mean? e.g. 03, 1h31
In my batch, none are the same with leads me to think they would not be bach codes.

Comment: Please add a picture. It probably is the production date code

Comment: Possibly a date or batch code? Without a photo its hard to say.

Comment: Ca you also please match your title to your question?

Comment: I could not make the question and the description in the same, can not ask a question without a description so i just split my question across the title and the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According the [datasheet, page 21](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl081.pdf) the device has a device marking "TL081CP".
The table has a footnote:

> <sup>(4)</sup> There may be additional marking, which relates to the logo, the lot trace code information, or the environmental category on the device.

which is explained in [Standard Linear & Logic Semiconductor Marking Guidelines](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza020c/szza020c.pdf)

**ALL** devices you bought should have this "TL081CP" marking. If not, you bought a counterfeit product or a complete different product.

Comment: perfect answer thank you.